# Add a field to a NetSuite inventory item bin

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

How can I add a couple custom fields to the Inventory Item Bin in NetSuite? On the Inventory Item page

[image]

In the Locations tab I want to add a couple more custom fields for the Item Bin

[image]

I've tried adding these fields to Customization > Lists, Records, & Fields > Other Custom Fields with a record type of "Bin", but they don't show up so I suspect this is not the correct location.

Comment: It might be that the custom Bin field is only visible when viewing a Bin record directly, and not when viewing it via the inventory form.

Comment: TonyH, you are right, they do show up on the Bin page, but I need them on the combination of Item and Bin. I don't know what this record is called.

Comment: Bin and Item are two different record type. A custom field can only be used within same record types. What are you going to do with the field?

Comment: I'm trying to add 2 fields Not Available Threshold and Available Threshold to tell an external system if this item code is available for selling. These 2 properties belong to the item code in this bin. I figure somewhere is a count of this item in this bin, that is the record I need to add the fields to.